# What my system.out.println coming out vertical

Tags: java

everything works perfect and I know more or less java sout formatting, but I ve been following this book and its been explaining how the logic works. One thing I can not seem to figure out is why my output is coming out vertical and in the book its perfectly horizontal? I have it formatted exactly the same way

this is my java code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package b.elsestatements;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author willc86
 */
public class Clock {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minuite = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        if (hour > 17){
            System.out.println("Good evening");
        } else if (hour < 12) {
            System.out.println("Goodmorning");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Good afternoon");
        }

        System.out.println("It is ");
        if (minuite != 0) {

            System.out.println("" + minuite + " ");

//            if (minuite != 1) {
//                System.out.println("minuites");
//            } else {
//                System.out.println("minuite");
//            }
            System.out.println((minuite != 1) ? "minuites" : "minuite ");
            System.out.println("Past");
            System.out.println((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12) : hour);
            System.out.println("O clock on ");

            //month case
            switch (month) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Jan");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Feb");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Mar");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Apr");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("May");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Jun");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Jul");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.println("Aug");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("Sept");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    System.out.println("Oct");
                    break;
                case 11:
                    System.out.println("Nov");
                    break;
                case 12:
                    System.out.println("Dec");

            }

            System.out.println("On " + year + " day " + day);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post an example of your output and the book (or desired) output.

Comment: `println` terminates each printed statement with a new line. If you want them on one line, use `System.out.print` instead.

Comment: Maybe, in the example uses println and print

Answer (score 2):

Maybe on your book it doesn't say: `System.out.println` maybe it says: `System.out.print`

```
System.out.print("" + minuite + " ");
System.out.print((minuite != 1) ? "minuites" : "minuite ");
System.out.print("Past");
System.out.print((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12) : hour);
System.out.print("O clock on ");
```

Maybe that should solve your problem.

I mean change `System.out.println` to `System.out.print`

And your **output** should look like this:

```
Good afternoon
It is 52 minuitesPast2O clock on Apr
On 2014 day 28
```

`System.out.println` will create a new line (`ln` on the end stands for line) so if you take it out, it should print horizontal without creating new lines.

Another way to create new lines on a `System.out.print` is by using escape characters such as `"\n"` that will do the same as `System.out.println`

This case:

```
System.out.println("Hello"); //Will create a new line
System.out.println("World"); //Will create a new line

System.out.print("Hello"); //Won't create a new line
System.out.print("World"); //Won't create a new line

System.out.print("Hello \n"); //Will create a new line
System.out.print("World"); //Won't create a new line
```

The output for the 3 cases above will be:

```
Hello
World

Hello World

Hello
World
```